# Creating a 'synchronization point' between threads

Tags: c++, multithreading, boost, synchronization, boost-thread

I have a couple of boost::threads which all execute the same function.

```
void foo(){
    //Lock Mutex
    //Do some stuffs, part 1
    //Unlock Mutex
    //Do some stuffs, part 2
    //Lock Mutex
    //Do some stuffs, part 3
    //Unlock Mutex
}
```

In order for my application to work, it is necessary that, before executing part 2 in parallel, all the threads have finished executing part 1.
I was not able to find any mechanism that would enable me to do that... am I missing something?

Thank you.

Comment: What you are looking for is called a barrier. I think there's one in boost.

Comment: use http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use Boost barriers. Definition from official documentation:

> A barrier is a simple concept. Also known as a rendezvous, it is a
>   synchronization point between multiple threads. The barrier is
>   configured for a particular number of threads (n), and as threads
>   reach the barrier they must wait until all n threads have arrived.
>   Once the n-th thread has reached the barrier, all the waiting threads
>   can proceed, and the barrier is reset.

extracted from [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_50_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.barriers).